# WHM Initial settings

Tags: cpanel, shared-hosting, whm

I am really new to this stuff. I have read online but cant figure out how to setup everything properly.
I have a domain from Bluehost

```
mydomain***.com
```

with nameserver

```
Default Nameservers
ns1.bluehost.com  74.220.195.31
ns2.bluehost.com  69.89.16.4
```

I have a dedicated hardware device with static ip 20.x.x.x. 
Now on the first step it asks for a hostname.
In /etc/hosts its

```
mydomain***.com
```

Should I give the same hostname here ?
Second in the third page NAMESERVERS what should I use. Should I be using the nameserver from bluehost?
I am really confused about this so If someone can guide me.

Answer (score 0):

You can set " Server.domain.com " as a server hostname and nameserver ns1 and ns2.domain.com.

Once you setup ns1 and ns2.domain.con, you will have to register this nameserver at your domain control panel with your server IP's

Comment: So in my case it would be registering those name servers from Blue host?

Comment: Also can't I just use Blue host dns? When I use my domain name from the browser I am being redirected to my machines ip. I have done settings in blue host only.